# What are the risks of wrapping Async/Await IAsyncOperations with Task.Wait() code?

Tags: .net, windows-runtime, async-await, c#-5.0

I'm currently trying to port a fair amount of existing synchronous code to WinRT.

As part of this, I'm hitting problems with the existing code expecting some operations to be synchronous - e.g. for file I/O

To adapt this existing code to work with the IAsyncOperation style API within WinRT, I've used a technique of wrapping the IAsyncOperation with an extension method like:

```
namespace Cirrious.MvvmCross.Plugins.File.WinRT
{
    public static class WinRTExtensionMethods
    {
        public static TResult Await<TResult>(this IAsyncOperation<TResult> operation)
        {
            var task = operation.AsTask();
            task.Wait();
            if (task.Exception != null)
            {
                // TODO - is this correct?
                throw task.Exception.InnerException;
            }

            return task.Result;
        }
    }
}
```

from [MvvmCross WinRT ExtensionMethods](https://github.com/slodge/MvvmCross/blob/vnext/Cirrious/Plugins/File/Cirrious.MvvmCross.Plugins.File.WinRT/WinRTExtensionMethods.cs) - with a similar method for `IAsyncAction`

These wrappers seems to work - and they allow me to use the `Async` methods in synchronous code like:

```
    public IEnumerable<string> GetFilesIn(string folderPath)
    {
        var folder = StorageFolder.GetFolderFromPathAsync(ToFullPath(folderPath)).Await();
        var files = folder.GetFilesAsync().Await();
        return files.Select(x => x.Name);
    }
```

I understand that this isn't really in the spirit of WinRT; but I am expecting these methods to normally only get called on background threads in the first place; and I am writing this with the goal of making my code cross-platform compatible - including to platforms which don't yet support await-async and/or to developers who aren't yet ready to make the jump.

So... the question is: what risks am I running by using this type of code?

And as a second question, is there any better way I could achieve code reuse for areas such as File I/O?

Comment: http://feedproxy.google.com/~r/AyendeRahien/~3/71OP6uo3bTQ/when-using-the-task-parallel-library-wait-is-a-bad-warning-sign

Answer (score 2, accepted):

I'm finally going to answer this....

And the answer is you can't really do it.

Even if you try to use some of the cleaner methods suggested in the other answers, then you still ultimately hit exceptions if you try to run the code on any thread which has promised not to block - e.g. if you try to run on the UI thread or on a threadpool thread.

So... the answer is you simply have to rearchitect that legacy code so that it's in some way asynchronous!

Answer (score 3):

First, I think your method could be rewritten as:

```
public static TResult Await<TResult>(this IAsyncOperation<TResult> operation)
{
    return operation.AsTask().Result;
}
```

Calling `Result` will synchronously wait if the task didn't finish yet. And it will throw an `AgreggateException` if it fails. I think throwing the `InnerException` like you do is a bad idea, because it overwrites the stack trace of the exception.

Regarding your actual question, I think the biggest danger with using `Wait()` together with asynchronous code are deadlocks. If you start some operation that internally uses `await` on the UI thread and then you wait for it using `Wait()` on the same thread, you will get a deadlock.

This is not as important if you're not `Wait()`ing on the UI thread, but you should still avoid it if possible, because it goes against the whole `async` idea.

Comment: Thanks for the answer. On the exception concern, I'm trying to make the surrounding code expect exceptions like FileNotFoundException - and I can't really expect them to handle AggregatedException's. Overall, though, this is *hopefully* a stopgap solution from me - in the longer term I'll either rewrite the Apis to use Action<T> based callbacks, or maybe I'll use await/async in the other platforms too (support is coming to MonoTouch and MonoDroid when vs11/C#4.5 comes out of beta!)

Comment: FWIW, his seems more in line with the await keyword since it gets the inner exception thrown instead of the aggregate.

Answer (score 2):

There's a lot of good reasons not to do this. See for example http://blogs.msdn.com/b/pfxteam/archive/2012/04/13/10293638.aspx

But if you want to do it, use the GetResults() method as follows

```
public static TResult Await<TResult>(this IAsyncOperation<TResult> operation)
{
    try
    {
        return operation.GetResults();
    }
    finally
    {
        operation.Close();
    }
}
```

Wrapping the IAsyncOperation in a task, as svick mentioned, works too but is less efficient.

Comment: I couldn't get this to work.  I tried the following code:

var folder = ApplicationData.Current.LocalFolder;
var items = folder.CreateItemQuery().GetItemsAsync().Await();

and got:

An exception of type 'System.InvalidOperationException' occurred
in the GetResults.  More information:  

A method was called at an unexpected time. (Exception from HRESULT: 0x8000000E).   AsTask().Result worked.

Comment: I had the same problem and is why I found this post. GetResults() did not work, but AsTask().Result worked fine