# Difference between the GetResults() method and the await keyword

Tags: c#, windows, asynchronous, async-await

Editing question:  In C#, when using a DataWriter object, why does "await dataWriter.StoreAsync()" work when "dataWriter.StoreAsync().GetResults()" causes a First Chance exception.  From how I understand the GetResults() method and the await keyword, they should both function correctly in this case.  I would like to understand the difference between the GetResults() method and the await keyword to know why one works and one does not in this particular case.

If I have a FileStorage object and call the DeleteAsync() method with the await keyword (await fs.DeleteAsync()) it works fine however if I use the GetResults() method (fs.DeleteAsync().GetResults()) I regularly get “First Chance Exceptions” of type InvalidOperationException.

I am trying to understand why await keyword works fine here but the GetResults() method does not (when I believe they should both work fine in this particular case) so I can have a better grasp on when I should use the GetResults() method and when I should use the “await” keyword.  This is for a Windows 8 Metro app.
Thanks

EDIT (adding the code from my test project)

```
private async void SavePressed(object sender, RoutedEventArgs e)
        {

            RenderTargetBitmap rtb = new RenderTargetBitmap();
            await rtb.RenderAsync(SignatureCanvas);

            IBuffer pBuffer = await rtb.GetPixelsAsync();
            byte[] pixels = pBuffer.ToArray();

            var fileName = "sig.png";
            var folder = Windows.Storage.ApplicationData.Current.LocalFolder;

            StorageFile file = await folder.CreateFileAsync(fileName, Windows.Storage.CreationCollisionOption.ReplaceExisting);

            Debug.WriteLine("----" + file.Path);
            DisplayInformation dispInfo = DisplayInformation.GetForCurrentView();
            using (var stream = await file.OpenAsync(Windows.Storage.FileAccessMode.ReadWrite))
            {
                BitmapEncoder encoder = await BitmapEncoder.CreateAsync(BitmapEncoder.PngEncoderId, stream);
                encoder.SetPixelData(BitmapPixelFormat.Rgba8, BitmapAlphaMode.Straight, (uint)rtb.PixelWidth, (uint)rtb.PixelHeight, dispInfo.LogicalDpi, dispInfo.LogicalDpi, pixels);
                await encoder.FlushAsync();
            }

            Debug.WriteLine(file.Path);

            saveSigToDB(file);

            await file.DeleteAsync();
        //    file.DeleteAsync().GetResults();

        }


private async void loadPressed(object sender, Windows.UI.Xaml.RoutedEventArgs e)
        {
            // TODO: Add event handler implementation here.
            DataStoreHelper dataHelper = DataStoreHelper.Instance;
            Signature sig = await dataHelper.getSignature(1);

            Debug.WriteLine("----" + sig.name);
            Debug.WriteLine("----" + sig.imgData);
            Debug.WriteLine("----" + sig.imgData.Length);

            InMemoryRandomAccessStream ims = new InMemoryRandomAccessStream();
            byte[] bytes = Convert.FromBase64String(sig.imgData);

            DataWriter dataWriter = new DataWriter(ims);

            dataWriter.WriteBytes(bytes);
          //  dataWriter.StoreAsync().GetResults();
            await dataWriter.StoreAsync();
            ims.Seek(0);
            BitmapImage image = new BitmapImage();
            image.SetSource(ims);
            SigImage.Source = image;


        }
```

EDIT2:  Added debug output for the FileStorage DeleteAsync() method, is this what you are looking for? I can not reproduce the StoreAsync() as it appears to be working correctly now with either the await keyword or the GetResults() method but not sure why when if was not working earlier.

```
'Test Signature.exe' (CLR v4.0.30319: DefaultDomain): Loaded 'C:\Windows\Microsoft.Net\assembly\GAC_64\mscorlib\v4.0_4.0.0.0__b77a5c561934e089\mscorlib.dll'. Skipped loading symbols. Module is optimized and the debugger option 'Just My Code' is enabled.
'Test Signature.exe' (CLR v4.0.30319: DefaultDomain): Loaded 'C:\Users\Tester\Documents\Visual Studio 2013\Projects\Test Signature\Test Signature\bin\x64\Debug\AppX\Test Signature.exe'. Symbols loaded.
'Test Signature.exe' (CLR v4.0.30319: Immersive Application Domain): Loaded 'C:\Windows\Microsoft.Net\assembly\GAC_MSIL\System.Runtime\v4.0_4.0.0.0__b03f5f7f11d50a3a\System.Runtime.dll'. Skipped loading symbols. Module is optimized and the debugger option 'Just My Code' is enabled.
'Test Signature.exe' (CLR v4.0.30319: Immersive Application Domain): Loaded 'C:\Windows\system32\WinMetadata\Windows.UI.Xaml.winmd'. Module was built without symbols.
'Test Signature.exe' (CLR v4.0.30319: Immersive Application Domain): Loaded 'C:\Windows\Microsoft.Net\assembly\GAC_MSIL\System.Runtime.InteropServices.WindowsRuntime\v4.0_4.0.0.0__b03f5f7f11d50a3a\System.Runtime.InteropServices.WindowsRuntime.dll'. Skipped loading symbols. Module is optimized and the debugger option 'Just My Code' is enabled.
'Test Signature.exe' (CLR v4.0.30319: Immersive Application Domain): Loaded 'C:\Windows\system32\WinMetadata\Windows.ApplicationModel.winmd'. Skipped loading symbols. Module is optimized and the debugger option 'Just My Code' is enabled.
'Test Signature.exe' (CLR v4.0.30319: Immersive Application Domain): Loaded 'C:\Windows\system32\WinMetadata\Windows.Foundation.winmd'. Skipped loading symbols. Module is optimized and the debugger option 'Just My Code' is enabled.
'Test Signature.exe' (CLR v4.0.30319: Immersive Application Domain): Loaded 'C:\Windows\Microsoft.Net\assembly\GAC_MSIL\System.Runtime.WindowsRuntime\v4.0_4.0.0.0__b77a5c561934e089\System.Runtime.WindowsRuntime.dll'. Skipped loading symbols. Module is optimized and the debugger option 'Just My Code' is enabled.
'Test Signature.exe' (CLR v4.0.30319: Immersive Application Domain): Loaded 'C:\Windows\Microsoft.Net\assembly\GAC_MSIL\System\v4.0_4.0.0.0__b77a5c561934e089\System.dll'. Skipped loading symbols. Module is optimized and the debugger option 'Just My Code' is enabled.
'Test Signature.exe' (CLR v4.0.30319: Immersive Application Domain): Loaded 'C:\Windows\Microsoft.Net\assembly\GAC_MSIL\System.Runtime.WindowsRuntime.UI.Xaml\v4.0_4.0.0.0__b77a5c561934e089\System.Runtime.WindowsRuntime.UI.Xaml.dll'. Skipped loading symbols. Module is optimized and the debugger option 'Just My Code' is enabled.
'Test Signature.exe' (CLR v4.0.30319: Immersive Application Domain): Loaded 'C:\Windows\system32\WinMetadata\Windows.UI.winmd'. Skipped loading symbols. Module is optimized and the debugger option 'Just My Code' is enabled.
'Test Signature.exe' (CLR v4.0.30319: Immersive Application Domain): Loaded 'C:\Windows\Microsoft.Net\assembly\GAC_MSIL\System.Diagnostics.Debug\v4.0_4.0.0.0__b03f5f7f11d50a3a\System.Diagnostics.Debug.dll'. Skipped loading symbols. Module is optimized and the debugger option 'Just My Code' is enabled.
'Test Signature.exe' (CLR v4.0.30319: Immersive Application Domain): Loaded 'C:\Windows\system32\WinMetadata\Windows.Globalization.winmd'. Skipped loading symbols. Module is optimized and the debugger option 'Just My Code' is enabled.
'Test Signature.exe' (CLR v4.0.30319: Immersive Application Domain): Loaded 'C:\Windows\Microsoft.Net\assembly\GAC_MSIL\System.Collections\v4.0_4.0.0.0__b03f5f7f11d50a3a\System.Collections.dll'. Skipped loading symbols. Module is optimized and the debugger option 'Just My Code' is enabled.
'Test Signature.exe' (CLR v4.0.30319: Immersive Application Domain): Loaded 'C:\Windows\system32\WinMetadata\Windows.System.winmd'. Skipped loading symbols. Module is optimized and the debugger option 'Just My Code' is enabled.
'Test Signature.exe' (CLR v4.0.30319: Immersive Application Domain): Loaded 'C:\Windows\system32\WinMetadata\Windows.Devices.winmd'. Skipped loading symbols. Module is optimized and the debugger option 'Just My Code' is enabled.
'Test Signature.exe' (CLR v4.0.30319: Immersive Application Domain): Loaded 'C:\Windows\Microsoft.Net\assembly\GAC_MSIL\System.Runtime.Extensions\v4.0_4.0.0.0__b03f5f7f11d50a3a\System.Runtime.Extensions.dll'. Skipped loading symbols. Module is optimized and the debugger option 'Just My Code' is enabled.
'Test Signature.exe' (CLR v4.0.30319: Immersive Application Domain): Loaded 'C:\Windows\Microsoft.Net\assembly\GAC_MSIL\System.Threading.Tasks\v4.0_4.0.0.0__b03f5f7f11d50a3a\System.Threading.Tasks.dll'. Skipped loading symbols. Module is optimized and the debugger option 'Just My Code' is enabled.
'Test Signature.exe' (CLR v4.0.30319: Immersive Application Domain): Loaded 'C:\Windows\system32\WinMetadata\Windows.Storage.winmd'. Skipped loading symbols. Module is optimized and the debugger option 'Just My Code' is enabled.
'Test Signature.exe' (CLR v4.0.30319: Immersive Application Domain): Loaded 'C:\Windows\system32\WinMetadata\Windows.Graphics.winmd'. Skipped loading symbols. Module is optimized and the debugger option 'Just My Code' is enabled.
'Test Signature.exe' (CLR v4.0.30319: Immersive Application Domain): Loaded 'C:\Windows\Microsoft.Net\assembly\GAC_MSIL\System.Configuration\v4.0_4.0.0.0__b03f5f7f11d50a3a\System.Configuration.dll'. Skipped loading symbols. Module is optimized and the debugger option 'Just My Code' is enabled.
'Test Signature.exe' (CLR v4.0.30319: Immersive Application Domain): Loaded 'C:\Windows\Microsoft.Net\assembly\GAC_MSIL\System.Xml\v4.0_4.0.0.0__b77a5c561934e089\System.Xml.dll'. Skipped loading symbols. Module is optimized and the debugger option 'Just My Code' is enabled.
----C:\Users\Tester\AppData\Local\Packages\a0c18bed-2eed-43e5-b052-d85765e6e8b1_fgj28ymhhr2yg\LocalState\sig.png
C:\Users\Tester\AppData\Local\Packages\a0c18bed-2eed-43e5-b052-d85765e6e8b1_fgj28ymhhr2yg\LocalState\sig.png
'Test Signature.exe' (CLR v4.0.30319: Immersive Application Domain): Loaded 'C:\Windows\Microsoft.Net\assembly\GAC_MSIL\System.Threading\v4.0_4.0.0.0__b03f5f7f11d50a3a\System.Threading.dll'. Skipped loading symbols. Module is optimized and the debugger option 'Just My Code' is enabled.
'Test Signature.exe' (CLR v4.0.30319: Immersive Application Domain): Loaded 'C:\Windows\Microsoft.Net\assembly\GAC_MSIL\System.Text.Encoding\v4.0_4.0.0.0__b03f5f7f11d50a3a\System.Text.Encoding.dll'. Skipped loading symbols. Module is optimized and the debugger option 'Just My Code' is enabled.
here
'Test Signature.exe' (CLR v4.0.30319: Immersive Application Domain): Loaded 'C:\Windows\Microsoft.Net\assembly\GAC_MSIL\System.Linq\v4.0_4.0.0.0__b03f5f7f11d50a3a\System.Linq.dll'. Skipped loading symbols. Module is optimized and the debugger option 'Just My Code' is enabled.
'Test Signature.exe' (CLR v4.0.30319: Immersive Application Domain): Loaded 'C:\Windows\Microsoft.Net\assembly\GAC_MSIL\System.Core\v4.0_4.0.0.0__b77a5c561934e089\System.Core.dll'. Skipped loading symbols. Module is optimized and the debugger option 'Just My Code' is enabled.
A first chance exception of type 'System.InvalidOperationException' occurred in Test Signature.exe
WinRT information: A method was called at an unexpected time.
'Test Signature.exe' (CLR v4.0.30319: Immersive Application Domain): Loaded 'C:\Windows\assembly\GAC_MSIL\Microsoft.VisualStudio.Debugger.Runtime\12.0.0.0__b03f5f7f11d50a3a\Microsoft.VisualStudio.Debugger.Runtime.DLL'.
```

EDIT 3:  I believe I captured what you were looking for.  I captured it based on this post:  [How do I find the stack trace in Visual Studio?](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/945193/how-do-i-find-the-stack-trace-in-visual-studio).

```
>   Test Signature.exe!Test_Signature.App.InitializeComponent.AnonymousMethod__1(object sender, Windows.UI.Xaml.UnhandledExceptionEventArgs e) Line 50  C#
```

Comment: There is plenty of information on this topic other there.  I find it hard to believe you couldn't find anything that describes what each of those two operations does.

Comment: Actually finding what they do is very easy, trying to figure out why one would work correctly and the other would throw a first chance exception is what I am having trouble with.  Also trying to understand when to use one over the other.

Comment: So if you know what they both do then don't ask what they both do, since you apparently already know.  Focus on describing what you *don't* know.

Comment: From what I understand about the GetResults() method and the await keyword they should both work without an issue however they do not.  That is why I am asking what the difference is between them and when I should use them.

Comment: If you seem to think they are interchangeable, then it seems you're not particularly familiar with what either of them are, at even a high level.  They are doing radically different things.  It sounds like you should be reading introductory tutorials on the topic of `await`, because trying to explain it is way too broad of a topic for an SO question.

Comment: WOW, why are you so against this question?  I never said they were interchangeable, I said that I believe they should both work for what I am trying to do.  I am trying to figure out why one is not working in my code and the other is so I can figure how to use them properly or maybe to find out I am doing something wrong in my code.

Comment: Please post the message and stack trace for both exceptions.

Comment: Instead of the debug output put in the exception information like a stack trace.

Answer (score 4):

The [`GetResults`](http://msdn.microsoft.com/en-us/library/windows/apps/br206600.aspx) that you are referring to is from [`IAsyncOperation(T)`](http://msdn.microsoft.com/en-us/library/windows/apps/br206598.aspx).

When you call `GetResults` the operation will run synchronously until the operation completes. This should be followed by [`Close`](http://msdn.microsoft.com/en-us/library/windows/apps/windows.foundation.iasyncinfo.close.aspx) when the object inherits from [`IAsyncInfo`](http://msdn.microsoft.com/en-us/library/windows/apps/windows.foundation.iasyncinfo.Aspx).

```
TResult result;
DataWriterStoreOperation task = dw.StoreAsync();

try
{
    result = task.GetResults();
}
finally
{
    task.Close();
}
```

The [`await`](http://msdn.microsoft.com/en-us/library/hh156528.aspx) operator is used on an `IAsyncOperation(T)` to suspend the execution state until the it completes.

The recommended way on the WinRT platform is to use `async` and `await` at all levels of the application. You would use the manual method when you are working with legacy non-async code.

```
TResult result = await dw.StoreAsync();
```

For your implementation you can reference [C# Windows 8 Store (Metro, WinRT) Byte array to BitmapImage](https://stackoverflow.com/a/18150413/580951).

```
private async void loadPressed(object sender, Windows.UI.Xaml.RoutedEventArgs e)
{
    // TODO: Add event handler implementation here.
    DataStoreHelper dataHelper = DataStoreHelper.Instance;
    Signature sig = await dataHelper.getSignature(1);

    Debug.WriteLine("----" + sig.name);
    Debug.WriteLine("----" + sig.imgData);
    Debug.WriteLine("----" + sig.imgData.Length);

    byte[] bytes = Convert.FromBase64String(sig.imgData);

    SigImage.Source = await ByteArrayToBitmapImage(bytes);
}

private async Task<BitmapImage> ByteArrayToBitmapImage(byte[] byteArray)
{
    var bitmapImage = new BitmapImage();

    var stream = new InMemoryRandomAccessStream();
    await stream.WriteAsync(byteArray.AsBuffer());
    stream.Seek(0);

    bitmapImage.SetSource(stream);
    return bitmapImage;
}
```

Make sure you dispose of the `SigImage.Source` when the application is suspended and reload on resume.

See also:

[What is the difference between Task<> and IAsyncOperation<>](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/10034239/what-is-the-difference-between-task-and-iasyncoperation)

[What are the risks of wrapping Async/Await IAsyncOperations with Task.Wait() code?](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/10668100/what-are-the-risks-of-wrapping-async-await-iasyncoperations-with-task-wait-cod)

For converting an `IAsyncOperation(T)` into a `Task(T)` use the extension method [`AsTask`](http://msdn.microsoft.com/en-us/library/vstudio/system.windowsruntimesystemextensions.astask).

Comment: If a post does not contain enough information to be answered then you should be voting to close with the relevant close reason, rather than posting an answer to say that you don't have enough information to answer it.

Comment: This question can be broken down into two parts: the `Difference between the GetResults() method and the await keyword` and the exceptions that the asker is encountering. This is really two questions. If the asker adds more information about the exceptions than I will be able to answer the second part.

Comment: According to [his comment](http://stackoverflow.com/questions/23251850/difference-between-the-getresults-method-and-the-await-keyword/23252225?noredirect=1#comment35579923_23251850), he knows what they both do, he just doesn't understand why he is getting the exception in each of the provides examples.

Comment: And according to his comment he is "Also trying to understand when to use one over the other." Which I believe is part of my answer. If you do not believe it is then I will add clarity.

Comment: I added the two functions that contains the calls in questions.  I will also take a look at your links.  Thank you Romoku